# I need to display the score and top five winning scores from an external file however I am not sure how to do so on python

Tags: python, sorting, project, mergesort, bubble-sort

I need to sort
from an external file and sort them from the biggest number such as 50 , Andrew being the person with the biggest score and then 0 , Andrew however I have been unable to do so.

I have tried using a bubble sort and splitting it after the comma in order to sort it from the largest to smallest however I have been unable to do so and I am stuck on this part for my school project and any help would really help me out.

The file is formatted in the form of :

```
-10 , Kevin
10 , Andrew
100 , Antonio
```

and ect

```
score = 0
open("score.txt")
scorefile = open("score.txt", "r")
file_contents = scorefile.read()
leaderboard = file_contents.split(",")
leaderboard = file_contents.split("\n")
```

Above is what I have got so far however not sure what to do after with bubble sort or something else when numbers can be unknown from a list. My scores are generated from a game which a person plays and is added to the file so the leaderboard should be able to change.

Comment: Each line in the file contains two pieces of information that go together: the score, and the person's name.  It makes more sense to read the file line by line, so you don't have to worry about mixing up a name with the _next_ person's score.  Don't use `.read()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.read()` function reads the file as an individual string. This may make it difficult to parse and sort. You may want to consider using the `.readlines()` function which will read and store each line as an element of a list.

Since this is a school project, I don't believe that it would be appropriate to discuss the entire solution, however, you should be able to use the concepts/ideas delivered by the code below to fit your needs.

```
# (Correction to program made) reads each line into list from text file
file_contents = scorefile.readlines()

# iterates over array and performs bubble sort
for i in range(len(file_contents)-1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i):
        if int(file_contents[j][:file_contents[j].find(" ")]) > int(file_contents[j+1][:file_contents[j+1].find(" ")]):
            file_contents[j], file_contents[j+1] = file_contents[j+1], file_contents[j]
```

You can then write the sorted list to the output file (be careful of '\n').

If you make this a function, you can call it once the text file is updated in order to ensure proper sorting.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: I have tried to use your bubble sort however when I print(file_contents) it is empty

Comment: Ensure that the file is being opened using the correct function, stored in the correct variable and that the file has contents. You could always add to the question or reply to the comment if you are still uncertain.